# How to Map an Entity to multiple tables and have also navigation properties?

Tags: entity-framework

I have and EMDX created with Database first, i have followed the sample described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715646), so now i can map one entity to multiple tables in my database, and this is working fine.

But i need also to have the navigation properties that the FKs provide on the tables on this one entity, how could i achieve that?

I have two tables, on named Carteira and another named Ativo, in my EMDX i want to have the properties of Ativo also to be on Carteira, because they have an 0:1 relationship, so i have done this already and it is working! :) but i also want the navigation properties that are in the Ativo class to be on Carteira

Please see a sample describing the properties :

```
    class Ativo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<Valor> Valores { get; set; }
    }

    class Carteira
    {
        public string AtivoID { get; set; }
        public Ativo Ativo {get; set;}
    }
```

So i would like to have something like
Carteira.Valores (and this should be infereed from Ativo).

Please note that i dont want to make this code manually using a partial class and acessing the navitation, i have already done this and i dont like this approach, it looks like this:

```
    public partial class Carteira
    {
        public List<Valor> Valores
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Ativo == null)
                    return null;
                return this.Ativo.Valores;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how to achieve this using the EMDX only, the same way that can be done for simple properties, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the navigations working in 2 differente ways:

**1 - Creating an 'Association' at the model (EMDX).** 
The associations work as if they were actual FKs, and since i already have the mapping collumns on both sides, it can be done by performing those steps:

Create a new Association at Carteira (second level class) that reflects the same properties of the FK present at Ativo (first level). When this is done, the navigation properties are created on both classes

**2- Using Table-Per-Type Inheritance**

In this specific scenario, the class could actually inherit from the other, and then take use of all of the navigations, for this to work i had to implement a TBT inheritance, altering the tables and adding "Conditional Mapping" to both tables (the concrete and the inherited) at the model (EDMX)

Answer (score 1):

For 0:1 to 1 relation,EF requires Foreign key to be same as Primary key on dependent table. So Ativo class must have Primary key of same name as AtivoID and that should be foreign key as well.

Comment: They are both PKs, but the problem is more complex,because i dont wanted to add a FK of Carteira (second level) to the related table, since Carteira (Second level) has a PK that is a FK of Ativo (first level). I actually created a "virtual" FK, using the Mapping feature in the model (EDMX). But you are right in your comment, it helped me find the right way to implement, so +1 to you :)

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you, you can add FK in SQL and not enforce it, in real world scenario we do have orphan records which do not have corresponding parent entry in referenced table. SQL allows you to turn off enforcing, however EF will still work correctly as it reads relations from SQL, enforcing of FK is independent of EF.

Comment: Yes, but since this is something i only need at application context (EF), it makes much more sense to do this directly at EF, since i wont be needing to add an FK that serves nothing at database level if EF already provides such a functionality.